# Unlock luks by other device

Tags: ssh, luks, crypttab

I know that by configuring **crypttab** I can automatically unlock **LUKS** drives by using keyfile stored on another drive in the machine which has been manually unlocked in advance. I have been wondering **if a keyfile stored in a different machine/device can also be used**, accessed e.g. over ssh.

**Here is what I would like to achieve.** A machine with an encrypted LUKS drive would at startup look at a particular IP address in the local network and if a device (android phone) is present, it would read a keyfile from the device and use it to unlock its drive, otherwise it would ask for password.

**Are there any better approaches to this?** I have found that there exists [blueproximity](https://github.com/tiktaalik-dev/blueproximity) which does something similar for lock-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible with LUKS 2 and [cryptsetup-ssh](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup-ssh.8.html). You can simply add the SSH token with

```
cryptsetup-ssh add --ssh-keypath=<path> --ssh-path=<path> --ssh-server=<ip/url> --ssh-user=<username> <device>
```

Where

- `ssh-keypath` is a path to SSH key to use to connect to the server,
- `ssh-server` is IP address or URL of the server,
- `ssh-user` is username to use when connecting to the server and
- `ssh-path` is path on the server where the key file can be found.

This will a so called token to the LUKS metadata (basically a small metadata blob containing above) and when you try to open the device with `cryptsetup open` it will try to use the data from the token to get the password.

Note that this is a relatively new feature (it was added in cryptsetup 2.4.0) and is still considered experimental and it is possible that your distribution doesn't ship cryptsetup-ssh. I am also not sure how well this works with systemd during boot.

An alternative is called Network Bound Disk Encryption (NBDE) which uses the Clevis-Tang client and server together with LUKS (both LUKS 1 and LUKS 2 are supported). You can read more about it in [this RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption_security-hardening).